# Google Chrome Inspector on Remote Devices not working for Сhromecast

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, adb, chromecast, chrome-remote-debugging

**I have a tv box**

- Android Pie
- chromecast built-in - 1.61.329909

**Done:**

- Enabled developer mode on tv box
- TV set-top box, android phone and laptop work in a common wi-fi network

**I am using adb to connect to a device.**

Commands:

```
adb tcpip 5555
  daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
  daemon started successfully
  error: no devices/emulators found

adb connect 192.168.1.87:5555
  connected to 192.168.1.87:5555

adb devices
  192.168.1.87:5555 device
```

adb is running and I can see the devices.

[device list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTtjD.png)

**i run cast on my phone and see video on tv.**

**Problem:**
The “inspect” link for the device is not visible. Because of this, I can't debug.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved.**

**Stages:**

- Did a full reset of the TV set-top box.
- Re-enable developer mode
- Connected all devices to a common wi-fi network
- Added a new chromecast built-in serial number to the Google Cast console